# Error [statusCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY ] while adding a user to a chatter group

Tags: apex, chatter

I am trying to add user to a chatter group from apex. I am getting an error

```
"Error [statusCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, code=[xmlrpc=1202, statusCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, exceptionCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, scope=PublicApi, http=400], message=This user can't be added to the group., fields=null]"
```

Here is the code i am using

```
lstCGM.add(new CollaborationGroupMember(CollaborationGroupId = lCGA[k].Chatter_Group_ID__c ,
                                                        // CollaborationRole = 'Member',
                                                        MemberId = u[i].Id  ));

//Debugging
    for(CollaborationGroupMember cgmr : lstCGM)
    {
        system.debug('Processing the CGM record ' + cgmr);
    }

    if (lstCGM.size() > 0)
    {
        // Insert the CGM Records
        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(lstCGM, false);

        // Loop through the save results writing errors to the debug log
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : lsr)
        {
            if(!sr.IsSuccess())
            {
                Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
                System.debug(err.getMessage());
            }
        }  // END LOOP through the save results writing errors to the debug log
    }// END IF there are records to insert, insert them.
```

The debug logs return the correct ids

```
Processing the CGM record CollaborationGroupMember:{CollaborationGroupId=0F9E00000008cpwKAA, MemberId=005c0000000R2kQAAS}
USER_DEBUG|[275]|DEBUG|This user can't be added to the group.
```

Checked the ids on the browser and they were valid.
Any idea what should be causing this?

UPDATE

This code on a after insert trigger on user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this error was that users with Chatter External license are considered as customers and these users cannot be added to a public group.

They can only be added to private group and with allow customers checked.

Hope this helps others who run into this issue.

Comment: Good finding @Prady !

Answer (score 2):

Most probably this comes because of invalid foreign key reference, please make sure that userId and Group Id are pointing to correct records. Also Is any of the object group or user deleted ?

By the way I tried a simplistic code with a couple of user license types, its working fine

```
Id grpId = '0F990000000Tgwv';
Id usrId = '00590000000dmJF';
insert new CollaborationGroupMember(
    CollaborationGroupId = grpId,
    MemberId = usrId);
```

The above code produces the same error if I try to add a user to a deleted group

```
19:42:52:041 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
```

Comment: Thanks Abhinav.. The user and group are correct i checked them on the browser. But i would think the issue is relating to adding chatter user to a public group. Are chatter users considered as customers?